# How to mount the BTRFS top sub-volume on Synology?

Tags: bash, raid, btrfs, synology

To track space that hasn't been reclaimed on large BTRFS raids there is a helpful tool called [BTDU](https://github.com/CyberShadow/btdu#usage).
To run it the top-level subvolume (-o subvol=/,subvolid=5) needs to be mounted.

So I'm wondering:

1. What is the bash command to mount the top-level subvolume
   (read-only)
2. Considering that child subvolumes are already mounted separately, is there any risk to mounting the top level one (as the child ones are inside of/beneath it)?

Thanks a lot!.